# How to get XSLT sum value of Nested for-each loop

Tags: xslt

I have for-each loop inside for-each loop.Now I want to get sum value for outside for-each loop.

below is sample XSLT code.Can anybody suggest

```
   <xsl:for-each select="s1:BankAccountTable">
       <xsl:if test="count(child::s1:BankChequeTable) >0">
            <xsl:for-each select="s1:BankChequeTable">
               <xsl:value-of select='s1:AmountCur/text()'/>
            </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? `sum(number(//s1:AmountCur/text()))` instead of a foreach.  Variables can't accumulate values in xsl. They only can be assigned once.

Comment: Can I use it outside for each loop?

Comment: Here I have two tables one bankaccount table(parent) and bank cheque table(child)..I want to get sum of amount for all bank accounts ..but amount is available in childe(bankcheque ) table ..can you please suggest..?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a sample of the input XML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.This is not to read or parse any xml this is to read table from data base in MS Dynamics AX(sqlserver).So I am not able to post any xml.

Comment: I have tried your above suggested statement but not working..

Comment: I have table with name Bankaccount which have the name and account number fields,and I have another table with name bankcheque which has the fields amount and chequenumber..there is relation between these two tables..Now What I want is sum of the amount for all bank accounts..